# Combine multiple files to one without headers

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am new in Unix scripting and Need some info on Unix cmd - 
Can we `cat` all file with a pattern like `abc_20190226_Part*.txt` in one file without their header in a unix command.

Comment: This is a reply: yes we can.

Comment: Apart from jokes, please be more clear, add details, show what you have tried until now. This the policy of this site.

Comment: How about `sed -s 1d abc*Part*txt > newFile`

Comment: Thanks Mark but sed-s is giving invalid option error. Although sed 1D abc*part.txt gives me concatenation but it also remove header from first file only.

Comment: Are you maybe on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

First some test files:

```
$ cat foo
11
12
13
$ cat bar
21
22
23
```

One way is to use `tail`. `man tail`:

```
-n, --lines=[+]NUM
       output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +NUM 
       to output starting  with  line  NUM
```

so:

```
$ tail -n +2 foo
12
13
```

but:

```
$ tail -n +2 foo bar
==> foo <==
12
13

==> bar <==
22
23
```

Oh nos, we need a loop around it:

```
$ for f in foo bar ; do tail -n +2 "$f" ; done
12
13
22
23
```

Another way is to use awk:

[GNU awk documentation](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_11.html) says:

```
FNR 
       FNR is the current record number in the current file. FNR is incremented 
       each time a new record is read (see section Explicit Input with getline). 
       It is reinitialized to zero each time a new input file is started.
```

so:

```
$ awk 'FNR>1' foo bar
12
13
22
23
```

Finally, you need to redirect the output to a new file (`one_file`), for example:

```
$ awk 'FNR>1' foo bar > one_file
$ cat one_file
12
13
22
23
```